# OSGeo4w: ogr2ogr script with FileGDB conversion working but getting a weird error : DATABASE.LAYOUT.VERSION.MINOR = 1 whereas a number >= 2 is expecte

Tags: gdal, osgeo4w

Full command below with dummy paths:

C:\OSGeo4W>ogr2ogr -f "FileGDB" "Path_to_some_geodatabase" "Path_to_some_geojson" -nlt POLYGON

---

Full errors below:

ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: C:\OSGeo4W\share\proj\proj.db contains DATABASE.LAYOUT.VERSION.MINOR = 1 whereas a number >= 2 is expected. It comes from another PROJ installation.

ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_identify: C:\OSGeo4W\share\proj\proj.db contains DATABASE.LAYOUT.VERSION.MINOR = 1 whereas a number >= 2 is expected. It comes from another PROJ installation.

---

More context:

The command actually appears to be working but those errors are interesting, and I haven't found anything online that mentions it.

Maybe I didn't install PROJ correctly when installing OSGeo4W?

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks etc.

Answer (score 3):

GDAL is using Proj library https://proj.org/ for coordinate transformations. The transformation parameters that Proj is using are stored into a SQLite database https://sqlite.org/index.html. The name of that SQLite  database file is "proj.db".

Proj library checks if the proj.db version is of the same version that the library is built to use. If it is not, it gives an error. Checking is done by making a SQL query into table named "metadata" that has among others fields "DATABASE.LAYOUT.VERSION.MAJOR" and "DATABASE.LAYOUT.VERSION.MINOR".

The image below shows metadata from my GDAL installation (from gisinternals.com).

[image: proj.db metadata in DB Browser]

That explains why you get the error message: the file in your path C:\OSGeo4W\share\proj\proj.db is wrong for the Proj version that ogr2ogr is using. Unfortunately I cannot say directly how to repair your OSGeo4W installation. I think I would try to use the installer in advanced mode and remove and re-install Proj-library first.

These lines in the advanced installer deal with Proj. The issue that you have would be triggered for example if dev version of GDAL expects dev version of Proj but finds only some older version.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I think you are right, I will give reinstalling a shot and post back again if it works, and give a breakdown of the steps I took - thanks for replying! I really appreciate it :D

Comment: Two years later, I still have the same problem. I have installed standalone GRASS `8.2` using the windows installer and a separate PROJ `9.2` using OSGeo4W advanced installer. I also set the `PROJ_DATA` environment variable according to the installation manual. Yet, I still have the same warning: `In system(syscmd, intern = intern, ignore.stderr = ignore.stderr,  :
  running command 'g.proj.exe -w' had status 1`